# How to access returned object by Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, object, return

I know how to access Javascript objects in general, but how to do this if that object is the returned value of a Javascript function that is triggered by default for a certain event?

Simplified example:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {

var obj = {
value1: 'val1',
value2: 'val2'
};

return obj;

});
```

How would I access the returned object?

Comment: In my opinion, You can't. You need to set it in a variable in the outer scope

Comment: You cannot - this function will be called as a response to an event but not by you. You can extract the function and call it manually or otherwise tap it, but not with the current implementation

Comment: Events are not designed to return values it's considered an anti-pattern (in the past people used the return to stop propagation). You cannot in this case and should consider other techniques e.g. triggering your own event, calling a function, writing to variables outside the function (e.g. global store) etc. Better to add what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks y'all for your useful comments. Durian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function

```
function getValue(value) {
    var obj = {
      value1: value.something,
      value2: value.someting2
    };

    return obj;
}

$(document).on('change', 'select', function(event) {

var result = getValue(event.target.value);

});
```